# Facebook Open Graph OG: Meta Tags - Works only sometimes?

Tags: facebook-like

I have a like button on my site, i have defined all the og: meta tags and its works for most of most pages, but doesnt for 2 other pages. Its using a template so its exactly the same code, how can it work for some but not all pages?

For the pages it doesnt work, it doesnt pick up the title, image, link or description, basically any of the meta tags information.

Working like button....
http://www.imoffonholiday.com/holiday.php?id=des_home&destination=faliraki

Not working Like button
http://www.imoffonholiday.com/holiday.php?id=des_home&destination=ayianapa

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One usual problem is caching.  If you were testing and at some point had the wrong data in the metatags facebook will cache that info.

One simple wat to test if it is a caching issue is to add a random param at the end of the URL.
so www.yourpage.com/index.php?cacheBust=1

Answer (score 0):

Running the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) often clears those kind of things up. It appears to refresh the FB cache when you do.